Partition function of harmonic oscillator using field integral
I'm currently reading Altland and Simon's Field Theory, and while trying to solve the partition function of the harmonic oscillator I ended up with a question.
Using a Hamiltonian of the form $H=\hbar wa^\dagger a$.
Using the formalism of the field integral with chemical potential to 0 and bosonic Matsubara frequencies, I arrived at
$$
Z=N\frac{1}{\sinh(\beta\hbar w/2)}
$$
Now this constant, $N$, from the derivation of the whole formalism should only have dependencies on temperature from what I understood, $\beta$ and not on the system parameters like $w$. $N\equiv N(\beta)$.
However if I used the standard way of just performing the sum
$$
Z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\beta(\hbar wn)}=\frac{e^{\beta\hbar w/2}}{2\sinh(\beta\hbar w/2)}
$$
Even if simillar we see that this constant brings a $w$ dependence, $N\equiv N(\beta,w)$.
I'm then confused if the constant $N$ we get from the field integral formalism can bring different physics or do we just ignore it since a partition function up to a multiplicative constant dependent on $\beta$  represents the same physical state.

You need to be careful how you define your path integral, the discretisation scheme will influence the continuum limit (like Ito vs Stratonovitch in stochastic calculus). Essentially, you missed out the zero point energy, which you can recover if you do the path integral carefully like in a previous answer of mine: Calculating free energy from coherent state path integral (look at the "single mode" paragraph)

Comment to the post (v2): Which page in A&S? Why is there no zero-point energy in $H$?
